# How to detect when HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv') is returned starts in Django Template?

Tags: django, ajax

I have a button in my template which when clicked converts a particular model to csv file and download begins.

```
<a href="{% url 'down' %}" >Download csv File</a>
```

The view:

```
def down(request):
    allobj=resource.objects.all()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resources.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Name','Email','Resource'])
    for obj in allobj:
        writer.writerow([obj.name,obj.email,obj.resource])

    return response
```

**Problem**: I want to show a loading gif as the model is pretty big. I can start the animation when the link is clicked, but I need to know when to stop it. So is there a way to detect in the template when the response is returned or when the download begins?

I know its easy to detect when a view has functioned successfully using Ajax, But how would I implement the downloadable link using ajax as it usually has a Json response but here I have a response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

Comment: Most browsers have a progress indicator when downloading files, is this not enough?

Comment: @IainShelvington I think you misunderstood. The view would take around 10-20 seconds to complete and then it would return the response and download will begin. So I want to show a spinning animation for that time(starting from when the user clicks the button till when the download starts)

Comment: Have you considered using a streaming response? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files